# Current Time Update MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update my field with current time during update query but its not working for some reason. My field Time is datetime type and Default set as Current Time stamp. I need update that time when I update one other field.
My Query is like this and working fine without update time

```
mysql_query("update tbl_quotes set quote_status='0' where id=".$_REQUEST['up_dea']."");
```

I have tried to update my time field with below query but its not updating....

```
mysql_query("update tbl_quotes set quote_status='0',Time=getDate() where id=".$_REQUEST['up_dea']."");
```

Let me know if someone know what is wrong with this...

Thanks

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Comment: It looks like you have too many double quotes at the end of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your table with:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY datetime_column DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

This way, every time when a record is updated, its timestamp will be updated.

Comment: Hi ! Do not want always update time during another query too....I just want update it with above query only.

Comment: Then just set your time_column = now() in that particular query.

Comment: mysql_query("update tbl_quotes set quote_status='0',Time=Now() where id=".$_REQUEST['up_dea']."");

Comment: like this ? or there any issue in my query ?